# R Remove punctuation between HTML tags

Tags: html, r, string, preprocessor, tm

I'm new with R and I have to use text mining on a data set with the following form

```
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DATE>08/31/2006</DATE>
<AUTHOR>Roy</AUTHOR>
<TEXT>I recently bought an 2007 Volvo XC90 with the 3.2 6 cylinder motor</TEXT>
<FAVORITE>The seats</FAVORITE>
</DOC>
```

And I need to do preprocessing but only between TEXT and
FAVORITE tags since I want to keep the HTML tags to extract dates later.

How can I do that? the regular function destroys the html tags.

`reviews <- tm_map(reviews, removePunctuation);`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hello you can use package `XML` to parse your HTML file and then access the tags you want :

```
writeLines(text = "<DOC>
<DATE>08/31/2006</DATE>
<AUTHOR>Roy</AUTHOR>
<TEXT>I recently bought an 2007 Volvo XC90 with the 3.2 6 cylinder motor</TEXT>
<FAVORITE>The seats</FAVORITE>
</DOC>", con = "example.html")

# Parse the HTML file with XML
library(XML)
your_html <- xmlParse(file = "example.html")
your_html <- xmlToList(node = your_html)
your_html$TEXT
# [1] "I recently bought an 2007 Volvo XC90 with the 3.2 6 cylinder motor"
your_html$FAVORITE
# [1] "The seats"

# Do what you want on your corpus
library(tm)
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(c(your_html$TEXT, your_html$FAVORITE)))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
inspect(corpus)
# <<VCorpus (documents: 2, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>

# [[1]]
# <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
# I recently bought an 2007 Volvo XC90 with the 32 6 cylinder motor

# [[2]]
# <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
# The seats
```